# How does $\frac{(-1)^xx(x+1)}{2}+(-1)^{(x+1)}(x+1)^2$ become $\frac{(-1)^x(x+1)}{2}(x-2(x+1))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify the following :

$$
\frac{(-1)^xx(x+1)}{2}+(-1)^{(x+1)}(x+1)^2
$$

and the solution online that I have found reaches this step :

$$
\frac{(-1)^x(x+1)}{2}(x-2(x+1))
$$

I do not understand how the "x" came down from the first fraction and how the addition suddenly became a multiplication between the two parts of the equation. What is the step between this ?

Comment: Is $x$ integer?

Comment: It's simply extracting a common factor, namely $$\frac{(-1)^x(x+1)}2$$ from both terms in the original sum.

Comment: gather the factor $(-1)^x(x+1)$, which is common to both members. Then develops the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring out $\frac{(-1)^{x}(x+1)}{2}$ we have $$\frac{(-1)^xx(x+1)}{2}+(-1)^{(x+1)}(x+1)^2$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^xx(x+1)}{2}-(-1)^{x}(x+1)^2$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{x}(x+1)}{2}(x-2(x+1)).$$